# Json object to string checking during while loop breaks page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, while-loop

I have a webpage that gets a json object from a url and then it turns the json object into a string. If the string is true I want the div to fade and if it is false I want it to stay the same.

The json object from the url is: { "description": "Input 1", "type": "no", "enabled": true, "alarm": false }

When an alarm is enabled, alarm = true. But I need to constantly check if the alarm is true or false so I need a while loop or another method of checking the url's json object constantly.

For some reason my method I'm using in the code below makes the page break.

When I take out the while loop, it works perfectly, but I have to refresh the browser to re-check the alarm object.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data;
            var r = true;
            do {


                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: 'http://192.168.1.6/inputs/alarm.cgi',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        // begin accessing JSON data here
                        console.log(response.alarm);
                        var j = (JSON.stringify(response.alarm));
                        console.log(j);
                        if (j == 'true') {
                            $('div').fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    }
                });
            } while (r == true);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
 div {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #FA6900;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: Tell all your friends - there is no such thing as a JSON Object - JSON is a string with specific notational requirements.

Comment: Okay, I'll also make sure to let them know that there's no such thing as a coffee object just mugs or cups.

Comment: Your basic problem is that you have ajax (which is asynchronous) inside of a synchronous loop.  Understand that the loop will actually continue before the ajax return.  If you want to loop with ajax you need to write in recursively.

Comment: @JackHudgins - you shouldn't confuse a programmatic structure with physical objects - it just highlights your misuse of the term further.

Comment: @JackHudgins not really, it would rather be that you think that your coffee object is a tree or a plane, That's fine if you want to believe it, but don't turn down a legitimate help that came free..

Comment: To chime in here, @JackHudgins JSON is a string format that allows for conversion of the string's contents into an actual JavaScript object. When the data is being transmitted, it's not an object, it's just a string (and that's because it's being transmitted via the Hyper**Text** Transfer Protocol). When it arrives `JSON.parse()` converts the string to a normal JavaScript object.

Comment: While I understand the JSON conversation going on in the comments, this is not productive towards solving the issue.

Comment: @RandyCasburn My comment wasn't about what's correct or not, or how informed or uninformed I am. I appreciate the help but not when it's condescending.

Comment: @Taplar Comments don't always address the exact issue. That's why they are comments.

Comment: Comments are intended to clarify the issue.  Not derail it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to make your "loop" a "chain" instead because of the asynchronous nature of making an ajax request.

In other words, you'll have to wait for the results of the first ajax request before making another ajax request.

```
var data;
var r = true;

function next(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'http://192.168.1.6/inputs/alarm.cgi',
        data: data,
        success: successful
    });
}

function successful (response) {
    // begin accessing JSON data here
    console.log(response.alarm);
    var j = (JSON.stringify(response.alarm));
    console.log(j);
    if (j == 'true') {
        $('div').fadeOut('slow');
    }

    // loop... assume some other logic controls "r".
    // Otherwise this will be an infinite loop
    // throttled by setTimeout.
    if(r == true ){
        // Delay calling next
        setTimeout(next, 5000); // execute next in 5000ms (5 sec)
    }
}


$(document).ready(next);
```

Comment: You might note that if they want some delay between the repetitions they could put a setTimeout on the call to the next() in done

Comment: Doesn't the `setTimeout` need to be in the `success` of the ajax call instead of an infinite loop?

Comment: The setTimeout is already in the success function. Many jquery-ites like to put the "success" function within the ajax {} block. I prefer to have a stand alone function and just reference the function name -- 6 of one -- half dozen the other. This setup is designed as an infinite loop, which can only be broken when "r" == false. There will be other logic in the overall app that controls the "r" value that's not show here. This function is throttled by both the ajax network request and the setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is freezing because your code is running REALLY FAST. You never limit the pace at which it makes calls, so it's going as fast as computationally possible, and the modern computer is an incredible math machine. While it's not the "perfect" solution, you can use a setInterval instead of an infinite while loop that will slow calls down.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  this.apiCall = function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'http://192.168.1.6/inputs/alarm.cgi',
      data: data,
      success: function (response) {
          // begin accessing JSON data here
          console.log(response.alarm);
          var j = (JSON.stringify(response.alarm));
          console.log(j);
          if (j == 'true') {
              $('div').fadeOut('slow');
          }
        }
    })
  }
  this.interval = setInterval(this.apiCall, 1000) //1 second intervals
}
```

edit: bob's answer is the formal way to make this call in perfect synchronousity, but you might still be making incredibly fast API calls. If it's impacting performance, I'd recommend my hacky method.

Comment: Personally I would still take bob's answer with potentially a setTimeout on the call for next in the done.  If the request ever takes over 1 second, this version would perform multiple calls simultaneously.  Bob's would not.

Comment: @Taplar That's a very valid point. You should ask bob to recommend that as part of his answer

Comment: @Taplar You're right again. I can never remember which callbacks in various function that you can and can't omit it :(

Comment: I only caught it cause i've done it twice in the last two days, lol.  Optionally you could do without the arrow function and just give setInterval `this.apiCall`